# Painting line over JPanel without repainting it

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I would like to have a vertical line drawn over a `JPanel`, and make it glide over it, without this process invoking the `paintComponent()` of the `JPanel`. I have thought of using the `GlassPane` but I don't think it is the correct way since there are other components in the frame containing the `JPanel`, and so it isn't specific to it (and I'm not actually sure it wouldn't call the `paintComponent()` anyway).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should be using [Layered Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) if you just want to isolate the line painting code from the rest of your painting code.

If your painting code is expensive, then maybe you should be creating a BufferedImage and then just redraw the image in your paintComponent() code. This is faster than repainting from scratch every time.

Comment: I know this question is old but I'd like to pick your brain if I can. If I add an animated gif to an ImageIcon, add that to a JLabel and add the JLabel to a JPanel, the cycling of the gif frames triggers the JPanel's paintComponent method. Is that really necessary? The gif is isolated to the icon/label. Can I stop the chain paint calling somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Even with a GlassPane the underlying component would have to be repainted at some point.  There is not a nice way to avoid a `paintComponent` call to JPanel.

However, the JPanel should not be doing things in `paintComponent` other than painting.  If you are trying to avoid calling it, then it sounds like you have something in the `paintComponent` method that needs to be changed or cached somehow.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I do have too much going on in the `paintComponent` method. I wanted to know if there was any technique that would work, before doing any caching...

Comment: The only technique that would work would be caching the pixels of the JPanel and repainting them on top with another pane. This would be tricky and problematic, especially as the frame size could change.  I would strongly suggest moving non-painting related actions out of the paintComponent method.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you do not want to call the paintComponent() method on the JPanel?  Repainting the object to render the line gliding over it will most likely be the easiest solution.